# How do I merge a parent fork?

Tags: git, github

I forked a project on github, since then the original owner made changes to it. How do I pull down those changes and merge them into my fork?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First set up a remote for the upstream repository, if you haven't already:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/...
```

Then fetch the remote contents and merge from it (assuming you're on the corresponding `master` branch of your fork):

```
git fetch
git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: You rarely want to work in the upstream's master. Unless you need it, I would skip the u-master creation.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: True. I don't think I've actually used it with GitHub in fact; I use it mostly when I have an upstream "template" repo of my own that I've "forked" into a number of child repos, from which I might want to make changes to the upstream template.

Comment: what does this mean? fatal: 'upstream' does not point to a commit

Comment: for some reason I had to pull it down, not just fetch... then it worked, thanks Will!

Comment: Because 'upstream' was not my default remote, this is what worked for me (which I guess is compressing the fetch and merge steps given above): `git pull upstream master`

Comment: "fatal: 'upstream/master' does not point to a commit" This doesn't work.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to follow the instructions above
`merge: upstream/master - not something we can merge`
BTW, I should add that the upstream is the parent of the parent. i.e. the parent of my fork is already forked from the repo I'm trying to merge into my repo