# node.js/karma/end-to-end testing: failed to proxy /app/index.html (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, testing, windows-8, end-to-end, karma-runner

The following are messages I'm getting while trying to run end-to-end test from AngularJS tutorial http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 on MS Windows 8 Professional. Could you please advise how can I make this test running well?

```
[2013-06-10 17:27:54.100] [WARN] config - "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: <<< Starting browser Chrome
INFO [launcher]: --- Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 27.0 (Windows)]: Connected on socket id E20UigDmDqhk3jaRRYAP
WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /app/index.html (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED)
```

[image: ECONNREFUSED while running end-to-end test using Karma node.js package on MS Windows 8 Professional]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you're seeing indicates that you haven't started the webserver.  Since you are using ./scripts/e2e-test.sh to run your e2e tests, you need to have your webserver serve the app from localhost:8000 and the docroot needs point to the angular-phonecat folder, not the app folder.  This can be done by simply running ./scripts/web-server.js (see [step-00](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00))

Note that there is a second way to run your e2e tests.  You can just visit

```
http://localhost:8000/test/e2e/runner.html
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well now. BTW, I'm using e2e-test.bat MS Windows batch file not e2e-test.sh

Comment: Something else is going on. My node web server was running when I got the error, and in my case, the test completed anyway (no fail). I restarted the node server, just in case, repeated the e2e test, and got the same result - warning and a completed SUCCESS test result. The localhost:8000/test also runs fine. Since the e2e test runs, its OK, but it would be nice to get rid of the warning. Something is not correct.

Comment: The Karma-e2e.conf.js file in the config folder declares the root as a proxy at http://localhost:8000/ which is where that setting comes from

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that the web server isn't running.  Its easiest to run a local one.

See the angular-seed (template project) at https://github.com/angular/angular-seed for details about how to setup a project (from this template) to be able to run testing.

Essentially:

- git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

  - I cloned as 'angular-seed-template-project' and use that as a template for my own projects.
  - I `git pull` on this to bring down the latest work and run `npm update` to pull in its latest dependencies
  - They actually say to fork angular-seed on git-hub which would allow you to easily `git pull` to update your project with the latest changes (as per [How do I merge a parent fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903416/how-do-i-merge-a-parent-fork)).  However my understanding is that you can only fork a github project once, which would preclude using angular-seed as a template.  Obviously I need to look at this in greater detail.
- `cd <the-project>`
- `npm test` to run the unit tests
- `npm start` to start the web server with the current-dir's app as the base.  This will not run as a processs by default so either do that in a different terminal to where you run the command-line commands or start as a process (which is called `node` that you will need to kill later) - `npm start &`
- `npm run update-webdriver` to install Selenium and more
- `npm run protractor` to run the end to end integration tests

Doing it this way as per the agile-seed instructions will avoid this error.